# UICollectionView showing unloaded xib and not updating the content inside using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view which is loaded from a .xib file. When the view opens sometimes the collection view will have loaded the content and other times it does not load any content into the cell causing just the .xib to be shown. Other times the .xib doesn't even show either. However, I don't understand why this is happening. When clicking on the cell, a new viewController opens with a detailed view which has the content loaded so the cell obviously knows what is suppose to be shown.

```
var currentUser: User!
var listCategories: [String] = ["Friends Lists", "Friends", "People"]
var lists = [Media]()
```

in `viewDidLoad:`

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ListCell2.0", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.listCell)
collectionView.reloadData()
observeMedia()
```

`observeMedia():`

```
func observeMedia() {
    Media.observeNewMedia { (media) in
        if !self.lists.contains(media) {
            self.lists.insert(media, at: 0)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

`viewWillAppear:`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    observeMedia()

}
```

`collectionView`  Methods:

```
extension HomeViewController
{

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return listCategories.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {

        return lists.count

    }else{
        return 0
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.listCell, for: indexPath) as! ListCell

    cell.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor.black, alpha: 0.08, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 10, spread: 0)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

    cell.currentUser = self.currentUser
    cell.media = self.lists[indexPath.item]

    cell.mainView.setGradientBackground(colours: self.getColourFromTag(tag: self.lists[indexPath.item].tag))

    return cell

}

//section header view
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    let sectionHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.sectionHeader, for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
    let category = listCategories[indexPath.section]
    sectionHeaderView.sectionTitle = category
    return sectionHeaderView
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.showListDetailSegue, sender: nil)
}
```

the CollectionView Cell

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SAMCache

class ListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
//@IBOutlet weak var tagLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var listTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var boughtLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var boughtProgress: UIProgressView!

var numOfItems = 0
var numOfBought = 0
var counter: Double = 0{
    didSet{

        boughtProgress.isHidden = false
        let fractionalProgress = Float(counter)
        boughtProgress.setProgress(fractionalProgress, animated: true)

    }
}
var currentUser: User!
var media: Media! {
    didSet{
        if currentUser != nil{
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
}

var cache = SAMCache.shared()

func updateUI(){

    let profileImageKey = "\(media.createdBy.uid)-profileImage"
    if let image = cache?.object(forKey: profileImageKey) as? UIImage {

        self.profileImageView.image = image

    }else{
        media.createdBy.downloadProfilePicture { [weak self] (image, error) in
            if let image = image {

                self?.profileImageView.image = image
                self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profileImageKey)

            }else if error != nil {

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }


    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //profile image

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //name

    nameButton.setTitle("\(media.createdBy.firstName) \(media.createdBy.lastName)", for: [])
    nameView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    nameView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //date

    dateLabel.text = "\(convertDateFormatter(theDate: media.dueAt))"
    dateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.3)
    dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    dateLabel.layer.cornerRadius = dateLabel.bounds.height / 2.0
    dateLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //title

    listTitle.text = "\(media.title)"

    //progress

    numOfItems = media.items.count
    print("num of items \(media.items.count)")
    counter = Double(numOfBought)/Double(numOfItems)
    boughtLabel.text = "\(numOfBought)/\(numOfItems) Bought"
    boughtProgress.layer.cornerRadius = boughtProgress.bounds.height / 2.0
    boughtProgress.layer.masksToBounds = true

}

@IBAction func arrowDidTap(){

    print("arrow tapped")
    print(media.tag)

}

func convertDateFormatter(theDate: String) -> String
{
    print(theDate)
    let newFormat = DateFormatter()
    newFormat.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dueDate = newFormat.date(from: theDate)
    newFormat.dateFormat = "dd MMM yy"
    print(newFormat.string(from: dueDate!))
    return  newFormat.string(from: dueDate!)

}
```

The first image shows when the view first loads. this is just what is shown in the .xib, however, the gradient has loaded, not the content

[image: collection view not loaded]

the second image shows how it should look. This is after scrolling through the view

[image: Collection View loaded]

Comment: It seems `currentUser` is `nil` when you are reloading the table for the first time, therefore it's not set on your cells and your `updateUI` is not even called.

Comment: Is it possible that `Media.observeNewMedia()` is calling back your code not on the main queue? If so, wrap you callback code in `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` .

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. @Yonat placing that in the viewDidLoad does not appear to work, however, when placing it in viewWillApear it works perfectly. Amazing how that one line of code fixes all the problems and only shows the collectionView when it has loaded. Cheers for the solution!